# Using a DTD to Specify an xml file with an element with free form

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an xml file which is specified for most of it. Only one element doesn't have specification and can contains arbitrary xml elements.

Here are an example of this xml:

```
<root_element>
  <specified_element>
     <empty_child_node/> 
  </specified_element>
  <element_with_free_form>
    <what><ever><xml><which><is><valid><xml>
    </xml></valid></is></which></xml></ever></what>
  </element_with_free_form>
</root_element>
```

My understanding of DTD is that this should be a valid spec for this kinds of xmls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!ELEMENT root_element (specified_element, element_with_free_form)>
<!ELEMENT specified_element (empty_child_node)>
<!ELEMENT empty_child_node EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT element_with_free_form ANY>
```

here is the full xml document with DTD embedded:

```
<!DOCTYPE root_element [
<!ELEMENT root_element (specified_element, element_with_free_form)>
<!ELEMENT specified_element (empty_child_node)>
<!ELEMENT empty_child_node EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT element_with_free_form ANY>
]>
<root_element>
  <specified_element>
     <empty_child_node/> 
  </specified_element>
  <element_with_free_form>
    <what><ever><xml><which><valid><xml>
    </xml></valid></which></xml></ever></what>
  </element_with_free_form>
</root_element>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `element_with_free_form` is declared as `ANY`, any element inside of it must also be declared. That means you would also need declarations for `what`, `ever`, `xml`, `which`, and `valid`.

Comment: Is it not possible element_with_free_form to be actually free form in another specification language ?

Answer (score 0):

As DevNull has already said, the `ANY` keyword means the element being declared can contain a mixture of `#PCDATA` and any element declared in the DTD.

If you want to declare that `element_with_free_form` can contain any well-balanced XML, then DTDs are not quite the right schema language for you.  XSD can declare such elements, as well as supporting some other variations like "I don't care what the structure is, but the children must all have been declared" (which is the same functionality as `ANY`) and "If you have a declaration for it, validate it, and if you don't have a declaration for it, let it ride" (which is a good first approximation to the "ignore what you don't understand" principle of HTML).